# view never dealloced

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

**Problem:**

I check every view with nslog to check if the view is dealloced,  detailViewController is never dealloced, after a while i get a memory warning, the only thing thats called is ViewDidUnload.

**How is the view called and what items are pushed to it**

The view is called and pushed in a table, in the detailViewController i have a searchResult that has:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) SearchResult *searchResult;
```

Here is the detailViewController called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

SearchResult *searchResult = [search.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
controller.searchResult = searchResult;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

//made a property with (nonatomic,weak) DetailViewController and set it to the    controller
self.detailViewController = controller;
}
```

**How is the detailViewController being disposed**

```
-(void)back:(UIButton *)sender{


[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

**What i think the problem is**

I am just guessing..
I alloc some functions that alloc some things in the detailViewController but if i go back then these stuff are automatically released right ?
it has to be something thats retained but i cant figure out what in the detailViewController i do have these private property's in detailViewController like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) iCarousel *carousel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

but if i get out of the view how can i release these objects ? or is'nt this the problem ?

UPDATE:

When i push back:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
```

LOG:

```
2013-01-13 19:33:30.703 App[21683:707] <UINavigationController: 0xfeafbf0>
2013-01-13 19:33:30.705 App[21683:707] (null)
```

I am using ARC

Comment: What view is never realloced? I can't tell what view you're talikng about.

Comment: @rdelmar sorry, i edited the question...but its the detailview

Comment: I don't see any detailView. Do you mean the detailViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar yes the detailViewController

Comment: You're keeping a reference to it with self.detailViewController, so it won't be deallocated until the instance of the class where you have this code, goes away.

Comment: @rdelmar i removed self.detailViewController, its still not Dealloced

Comment: Sorry,, missed the fact that the property was weak, so that shouldn't be the problem (but there's no use for that line either).

Comment: The property for the searchResult should be `strong` instead of `weak`. And the `self.detailViewController = controller;` should just be removed. Can you add a NSLog() when you pop the viewcontroller?

Comment: NSLog that you sucessfully popped the viewcontroller

Comment: What are you logging? And are you using ARC or not?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
I am using ARC yes

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some strong references to the detailViewController.

In your didSelectRow method. You are creating a strong reference with this code:

```
self.detailViewController = controller;
```

After the detailViewController has been popped or when you receive a memory warning, just set

```
self.detailViewController = nil;
```

If this doesn't work check your other code to see if you are creating any other strong references or retain loops where the detailViewController may have a strong reference to the calling view controller.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After storing `controller` in `self.detailViewController` you have to release controller, since it was allocated earlier in this method. So the code will become

```
self.detailViewController = controller;
[controller release];
```